# Minimum depth of function calls

Tags: c, function

A function can call another function. This usually adds some overhead and can e.g. result in a stack overflow.

Such a limitation complicates portability, so does the standard require a minimum possible depth of a a chain of function calls?

To clarify, suppose

```
double fac(unsigned int n) {
    return n == 0? 1: (double)n * fac(n - 1);
}
```

then what `n` is the largest possible input where `fac(n)` is guaranteed to behave as expected?

Comment: I cannot see how the standard could possibly guarantee anything like that.

Comment: I doubt it. This is a system issue, not part of the standard. I don't even think that the standard speaks about a stack. Implementations could do it differently. The stack size is an adjustable linker setting.

Comment: I am not even sure the standard can guarantee `int stackoverflow() {return stackoverflow();} ` will raise a stack overflow...

Comment: The limit is memory not recursive depth.  Different implementations will use different amounts of memory depending on how they optimize your code. E.g. your example is tail recursive so some implementations will optimize this function to use a much smaller amount of memory than others.